# Keyword spotting is not activated in pocketsphinx_continuous

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I tried to adapt CMU Sphinx to my accen using the [guide](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt).

I'm unable to do keyword spotting with the this model with this command -

```
pocketsphinx_continuous \
 -hmm /Desktop/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-5prealpha/model/en-us-adapt/en-us-adapt/   \
 -lm /Desktop/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-5prealpha/model/en-us-adapt/en-us.lm.bin   \
 -dict /Desktop/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-5prealpha/model/en-us-adapt/cmudict-en-us.dict \
 -infile /Downloads/Record_0011Cleaned.wav \
 -kws /Desktop/cmusphinx/KeyPhrase2.txt \
 -logfn /dev/null \
 -time yes > /tmp.txt
```

`pocketsphinx_continuous` seems to be looking for all the words that are available to it in the dictionary and not just those defined in my keyphrase file. The output additionally includes tags like `<s>`,  `/s>` and so on. Neither of these happen if I remove the `hmm`, `lm`, and `dict` arguments.

Why is this happening and what can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify either language model search with `-lm` argument or keyword search with `-kws` argument, not them together. `-lm` has higher priority and is used instead of `-kws` in your case.

To solve the problem remove `-lm` part from your command line.